# Using plt.fill_between on a scatter plot draws extra lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

I’m plotting a scatter plot where the last point is the same as the first point and using fill_between to shade the interior. For some reason it draws a vertical line from the first/last point down to the x axis, and another horizontal line along the x axis from the lowest x value to the highest. How can I make it not draw those lines?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [38, 72, 7, 64, 6, 64, 44, 96, 75, 25, 38]
y = [58, 29, 4, 100, 41, 56, 45, 55, 16, 13, 58]

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.fill_between(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Scatter plot with fill_between and extra lines:
[image: Scatter plot with fill_between and extra lines]

Comment: Your matplotlib version it pretty old. [This is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plqDi.png) what the code would give in a newer version.

Comment: Thanks Ernest, that sounds reasonable! I’m using Pythonista 3.0 on an iPad so I don’t believe I have any control over the matplotlib version, but I’ll ask on the product forum.